# Split list indexes into new lists python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an intro to programming lab using python. I want to split a list:

```
items = ['40/40', '10/40', '30/40', '4/5', '18/40', '40/40', '76/80', '10/10']
```

into two new lists:

```
items_1 = ['40','10','30','4','18','40','76','10']

items_2 = ['40','40','40','5','40','40','80','10']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: As part of their answer, someone is going to suggest performing a transpose with `zip(*something)`. Keep in mind that that doesn't work if `items` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```
items = ['40/40', '10/40', '30/40', '4/5', '18/40', '40/40', '76/80', '10/10']
items_1 = list()
items_2 = list()

for item in items:
  i_1, i_2 = item.split("/") #Split the item into the two parts
  items_1.append(i_1)
  items_2.append(i_2)
```

**Result** (from the IDLE shell)

```
>>> print(items_1)
['40', '10', '30', '4', '18', '40', '76', '10']
>>> print(items_2)
['40', '40', '40', '5', '40', '40', '80', '10']
```

It works *even when* `items` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

So here is the standard `zip` one-liner. It works when `items` is non-empty.

```
items = ['40/40', '10/40', '30/40', '4/5', '18/40', '40/40', '76/80', '10/10']

items_1, items_2 = map(list, zip(*(i.split('/') for i in items)))
```

The `map(list(..))` construct can be removed if you are happy with tuples instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

First split the elements of `items` (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001247/fastest-way-to-split-a-concatenated-string-into-a-tuple-and-ignore-empty-strings)), then zip them (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip)):

```
items = ['40/40', '10/40', '30/40', '4/5', '18/40', '40/40', '76/80', '10/10']

items_tuples = map(lambda x: x.split('/'), items)

items_1, items_2 = zip(*items_tuples)
```

But note that this will cause a `ValueError` if you ever call it when `items` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these methods :

```
items = ['40/40', '10/40', '30/40', '4/5', '18/40', '40/40', '76/80', '10/10']

print(list(zip(*[i.split('/') for i in items])))
```

or

```
print(list(zip(*(map(lambda x:x.split('/'),items)))))
```

output:

```
[('40', '10', '30', '4', '18', '40', '76', '10'), ('40', '40', '40', '5', '40', '40', '80', '10')]
```